# Setting proper User permissions in VSftpD (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I recently set up an Ubuntu Server (32-bit, 11.04) and setup LAMP. I'm trying to configure VSftpD so I can transfer files locally from my laptop to the Ubuntu server.

I was able to follow various tutorials to create the CHroot user list. I was able to properly set the default root folder to my vars/www. For some reason my login is unable to edit files or folders. I am currently using my root user, I was unsure on how to create a Virtual user.

Any info or pointing in the right direction would be of much help. After 3-4 hours of searching through blogs, tutorials, and forums I figured I would give this a shot.

** Disclaimer - I used the search feature but couldn't seem to find anything relevant to my issue.**

**RESOLVED**

I figured out the issue, the permissions of the folders were not properly set. I entered the following and now my user has 100% access

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /var/www 
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

**RESOLVED**

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/267919/setting-up-vsftpd-permissions-with-apache-server

Answer (score 7):

the sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www command is not preferable as most servers will throw a 500 error for security reasons, visit this for more information http://tutorials.ausweb.com.au/web-hosting/php-and-mysql/solving-a-500-internal-server-error.html